# Regarding the Views in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm developing an page, where on the role basis the content should be displayed.For example, if I'm an adviser, i should see only few content or contents related to mine.Where as administrator can see all the content.Also whenever adviser sends any request for accessing any content, admin should have an option to "grant" or "deny". I'm using just a share point designer to achieve this. Does this implementation need any custom logic? if yes can anyone please provide me a code to achieve this?

I do searched a lot, but didn't got any related information. Please provide me a link.

Comment: what version are you running? 2010, 2013? on prem? foundation/server?

Comment: @Tiago;I'm using 2010 and 2013.I need to implement in both.

Answer (score 1):

sounds to me like target audiences.

you can create multiple webparts on the page and set different target audiences on each of them, according to the users or groups you need. this will effectively display different content to different types of users but it is not available on foundation

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-targeting-content-on-a-sharepoint-site-to-specific-audiences-HA010243222.aspx